# InterSystems IRIS Provider Communication link failure: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException in C#

Tags: database, intersystems-cache, intersystems-iris

I'm using VS Studio 2017 and InterSystems IRIS databases version 2019.1.
When i'm trying to access database from code it will throwing below error:

> InterSystems.Data.IRISClient.IRISException: '[IRIS Provider] Communication link failure: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException; No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:1972

Below are my code snippet.

```
// Using IRISADOConnection to connect
IRISADOConnection connect = new IRISADOConnection();

// Create connection string
connect.ConnectionString = "Server = localhost; Port = 1972; Namespace =  User; Password = abcd@1234; User ID = _system";
connect.Open();
connect.Close();
```

Let me know if you have any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it just can't connect to database port. In iris default port is 51773. Check your configuration in management portal.

Is any of this on container by any chance?